# BASIC GRIDVIEW: How to properly present Gridview with NULL database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, gridview

My gridview doesn't show anything because my database is null. How can I display even just the controls so I could start transacting? Is there a way to properly present the datagrid even if it's null? Maybe even just the columns of the table displaying?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please include some code to show us the specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this  `ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"`

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

If you need display no record found message in codebehind

```
if(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count==0)
{
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(ds.Tables[0].NewRow());
gvdata.DataSource = ds;
gvdata.DataBind();
int columncount = gvdata.Rows[0].Cells.Count;
gvdata.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
gvdata.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
gvdata.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = columncount;
gvdata.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Records Found";
}
```

[Asp.net show gridview header when there is no data or empty](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/12/v-behaviorurldefaultvmlo.html)

Comment: Thanks sir! A very helpful answer for a very simple question. :D

Answer (score 1):

there is a property called [`ShowHeaderWhenEmpty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.showheaderwhenempty.aspx) ,set it as `true`